# PyCharm not detecting anaconda3 environments

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I have installed anaconda3, and created some environments from the command line:

```
(base) ➜  ~ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
scratchpad               /Users/adamg/.conda/envs/scratchpad
test                     /Users/adamg/.conda/envs/test
base                  *  /Users/adamg/anaconda3
convokit                 /Users/adamg/anaconda3/envs/convokit
scholar                  /Users/adamg/anaconda3/envs/scholar
swda                     /Users/adamg/anaconda3/envs/swda
```

However, in PyCharm, none of these environments show up. In addition, as seen below, on the screen "Add Python Interpreter" there is a message at the bottom that says "Conda executable not found". I've tried to find solutions using that error message, but have not come up with anything.
[image: pycharm screen]

What am I missing here?

I am running PyCharm Professional 2019.2, and MacOS 10.15.

Comment: So first set up the `Conda executable`, you should be able to choose a correct path. Then all your environments should be detected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the Python path.

Activate into the desired environment `source activate swda`, Run `which python` from to locate the Python path that is under Anaconda, and then press the three dots `...` right to the "interpreter" and paste the python path.

Or simply look for the Python executable through the UI and add it as the interpreter.

Comment: I think I'm a bit confused. This adds the general interpreter for Python 3.7, but the environments I created in anaconda are not showing up.

Comment: @Adam_G There is a Python executable under the Anaconda directory as well

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by that. `which python` does point to `/Users/adamg/anaconda3/bin/python`, which is the python executable under anaconda, right? But what individual enviorments like `swda`?

Comment: @Adam_G Try to activate the virtualenv and then running `which python`. It's `source activate swda` I think, and then `which python` will point to the correct Python path

Comment: This still seems to be missing what I'm looking to do. Shouldn't PyCharm be able to recognize all of the environments I've created in anaconda, and then allow me to choose one?

Comment: Not that I know of. For every virtualenv you create you should add the corresponding paths.

Comment: Interesting. I did not realize that

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Pycharm does not show the existing conda environments. In that case, just point to the python path of the existing conda environment through venv and it will recognize it as a conda env.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33037961)

Answer (score 1):

I used the following steps to fix a similar problem.
This method may help you too.

1. Click `add interpreter`
2. Click `conda environment`
3. Click [`'file bag'`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apkj0.png) flag like this
4. Select the folder `condabin` and choose file [`'conda.bat'`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/802yX.png) (cause we need to connect anaconda with pyCharm, instead of `python.exe`)
5. I guess you will find the button- `existing environment` and `create new environment` after you click `load environment`, per the following :
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EODls.png)
6. Then you can add whatever virtual environment (existing or new).

Answer (score 0):

If you have an invalid Conda environment, you need to delete it and the one missing will show in the list.